# UI Router states. not setting right by changing the url. - angular ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I past many solutions and tutorials already, without found a right answer. So I hope I don't make a duplicate and give us a nice little challenge here

use

`angular`

`ui router`

**Problem**

I have some states and those states have their own unique url. I click on link (ui-sref) the state and url changing correctly. however when I set the url (for example "localhost:8080/user") and click 'Enter' on my keybord. the current state change to some 'empty state' without nothing even if the url setting correctly

**Code**

config :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('divohon-app').config(function ($stateProvider,  $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {


    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });

    $stateProvider
        .state("user-home", {
            url: "user",
            templateUrl: "/resources/html/template/user-home.html",
            controller: "UserHome",
            controllerAs: "uhCtrl"
        })
        .state("admin-home", {
            url: "admin",
            templateUrl: "/resources/html/template/admin-home.html",
            controller: "AdminHome",
            controllerAs: "ahCtrl"
        })
        .state("login", {
            url: "login",
            templateUrl: "/resources/html/template/login.html",
            controller: "LoginController",
            controllerAs: "lCtrl"
        });
});
```

Thank you for any help. or reference.

Comment: try `localhost:8080/#/user` adding the #

Answer (score 0):

You just have to update url property of each state as `/user` , `/admin` , `/login` respectively. It should solve the problem.

```
$stateProvider
.state("user-home", {
    url: "/user",
    templateUrl: "/resources/html/template/user-home.html",
    controller: "UserHome",
    controllerAs: "uhCtrl"
})
.state("admin-home", {
    url: "/admin",
    templateUrl: "/resources/html/template/admin-home.html",
    controller: "AdminHome",
    controllerAs: "ahCtrl"
})
.state("login", {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: "/resources/html/template/login.html",
    controller: "LoginController",
    controllerAs: "lCtrl"
});
```

After above change localhost:8080/user should correctly show the view.